# Java3D draw solid area/cube from points

Tags: java, opengl, 3d, geometry, java-3d

I have a list of points that I want to draw as a solid area.
I can draw the points as a LineStripArray (see image).
But when I try to draw the points as IndexedTriangleArray / IndexedQuadArray, I get a weird shape. I also tried it with GeometryInfo and Stripifier but with no success.

[image: Points connected trough a linestrip]

**Code with GeometryInfo:**

```
    GeometryInfo geometryInfo = new GeometryInfo(GeometryInfo.QUAD_ARRAY);
    geometryInfo.setCoordinates(points3f);

    NormalGenerator normalGenerator = new NormalGenerator();
    normalGenerator.generateNormals(geometryInfo);

    Stripifier st = new Stripifier();
    st.stripify(geometryInfo);

    Shape3D shape = new Shape3D();
    shape.setAppearance(app);
    shape.setGeometry(geometryInfo.getGeometryArray());
```

**Solution for an area (plus new question):**

```
Appearance app = new Appearance();

PolygonAttributes pa = new PolygonAttributes();
pa.setCullFace(PolygonAttributes.CULL_NONE);
pa.setPolygonMode(PolygonAttributes.POLYGON_FILL);
app.setPolygonAttributes(pa);

GeometryInfo geometryInfo = new GeometryInfo(GeometryInfo.POLYGON_ARRAY);

geometryInfo.setCoordinates(points3f);
int[] stripCountArray = { points3f.length };
int[] countourCountArray = {stripCountArray.length};

geometryInfo.setContourCounts( countourCountArray );
geometryInfo.setStripCounts( stripCountArray );

NormalGenerator normalGenerator = new NormalGenerator();
normalGenerator.generateNormals(geometryInfo);

Shape3D shape = new Shape3D();
shape.setAppearance(app);
shape.setGeometry(geometryInfo.getGeometryArray());
```

The shape also has a depth. But I can't just copy the array add the Z-index and merge them again (that wont work). A possible solution is to draw every face separately, but I think that will be very inefficient.

Does some one can help me with this problem?

Comment: Do you really provide your data as Quads? Also winding must be CCW.

Comment: @sonofthenortherndarkness Some. I have a range of shapes with points count: 4, 8, 9, and 12. But if the count is a multiple of 3 of 4 it should be ok to use Quads and triangular arrays. The problem is that I don't know where to make the squares/triangles because the shape is not always the same.

Comment: Ok... Then you need to look at the direction of triangulation algorithms. I think you can find the information very easily. This is the first from Google on "triangulation algorithms". http://vterrain.org/Implementation/Libs/triangulate.html

Comment: @sonofthenortherndarkness Thank you, I have not a lot of experience in 3D drawing but I like to learn more. I will look into it!

Comment: @sonofthenortherndarkness I have it working for an area but now I want the area to have a depth (so it is 3D). I will update my question for it.

Comment: It looks like you have to provide other polygons in points3f, information on where one polygon data ends and other starts is implicitly providied in length arrays.

Comment: @sonofthenortherndarkness I was planning to create and calculate the different strips of the object.

Comment: You say this object has a depth now too?  Then you can just use a pair of (interlocking) Box objects, can't you?  One using 1,2,7,8 and another using 11,4,5,10.  Or is the problem more general?